# VSTO outlook data issue through exchange sync

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I wrote an addin for outlook, It will popup appointment's LastModificationTime while I click button

the button eventhandler like this

```
  Outlook.ApplicationClass outlook = new Outlook.ApplicationClass();
  Outlook.NameSpace ns = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
  Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
  Outlook.Items FolderItems = folder.Items;
  DateTime MyDate = DateTime.Now;
  List<Outlook.AppointmentItem> Appts = (
       from Outlook.AppointmentItem i in folder.Items
       where i.Start.Month == MyDate.Month && i.Start.Year == MyDate.Year
       select i).ToList();
  foreach (Outlook.AppointmentItem Appt in Appts)
  {
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Appt.LastModificationTime.ToString());
  }
```

the issue is happened while I changed appointment in my mobile phone, then sync it to the outlook through exchange server

steps which makes issue:

1. click button, get LastModificationTime as "time1"
2. change start date as "start1" in my mobile phone, sync to outlook through exchange server
3. click button, get LastModificationTime, still "time1"
4. change start date as "start2" in outlook, but the appointment is still in "start1" date.
5. restart outlook
6. click button, get new LastModificationTime as "time2", and appointment is in "start1" date, "start2" is gone.

steps without issue

1. click button, get LastModificationTime as "time1"

1.1. restart outlook

2. change start date as "start1" in my mobile phone, sync to outlook through exchange server
3. click button, get LastModificationTime, "time2"

It looks like 
List Appts
is never been refreshed to latest value if the appointment is changed through exchange server.

Is there any solution for this issue? or other reason to make it happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not seeing you other code, but you need to remember to release the appointment objects
Marshal.ReleaseComObject.
Also is your client outlook in cache mode?

Marcus

Comment: Hi,

Thanks, I tested Marshal.ReleaseComObject, it works!!!
but another issue is out while I access appointment's recipients, it does not release object, and still give old LastModificationTime  value

only added below inside loop:
if (Appt.Recipients.Count > 0)
{
}

Comment: Can you explain abit more ? are you saying the Appointment won't release if you run through its Recipients ?

Comment: Yes, appointment wont be released if I use Appt.Recipients.Count.Using apptrecipents = Appt.Recipients, then apptrecipents.Count, all is fine now. Thanks.

Comment: yes that is the way you have to declare it and then release that.

Answer (score 0):

I've had same issue, and this is my solution:

Use:

```
Outlook.Folder calFolder = outlookApplication.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar) as Outlook.Folder;
```

Instead of:

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
```

The difference is  Outlook.MAPIFolder and Outlook.Folder, I don't known why but Outlook.Folder works for me.